# Nginx: different content to specific request method

Tags: linux, images, nginx, webserver

I have the image in the URL (my server): `http://www.example.com/example.jpg`

If my user put this image URL on his site: return the image (normal).

If my user put this image URL on his browser: return redirect to my site, i.e. `http://www.example.com/?fimage=example.jpg`

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

**Hello Caio Tarifa**,

The following solutions works on my nginx dev server on Windows.

In nginx.conf, add the following to your main server instance.

```
location ~ \.jpg$ {
    root   html; // edit if you use a different path to your server root.
    index  index.html index.htm; // edit if you use other file types
}
```

If this solution doesn’t work for your configuration, take a look at the following sites:

[NginX Http Rewrite Module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule)

[NginX.Conf - Full Example](http://wiki.nginx.org/FullExample).